# FileNotFoundException when reading file in resources folder

Tags: java, file

Code:

```
  String filePath = "src//main//resources//QR_CODE//QR_Code.png";
            //String filePath = "C:\\Work\\QR_CODE\\QR_Code.png";
            String charset = "UTF-8"; // or "ISO-8859-1"
            Map <EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel> hintMap = new HashMap < EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel > ();
            hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);
            BitMatrix matrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(
                    new String(qrCodeData.getBytes(charset), charset),
                    BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 200, 200, hintMap);
            MatrixToImageWriter.writeToFile(matrix, filePath.substring(filePath
                    .lastIndexOf('.') + 1), new File(filePath));
```

Output:

```
12:33:09,948 ERROR [stderr] (default task-17) java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\QR_CODE\QR_Code.png (The system cannot find the path specified)
12:33:09,948 ERROR [stderr] (default task-17)   at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
12:33:09,950 ERROR [stderr] (default task-17)   at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
12:33:09,950 ERROR [stderr] (default task-17)   at java.io.RandomAccessFile(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
12:33:
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A compiled program contains compiled classes and program resources.  It does not and should not contain the project’s source directory.  Furthermore, you cannot and must not try to modify your program at runtime.  If you want to save an image, don’t try to write inside your program;  write to a known external location, like a subdirectory of the system’s temporary directory.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use dynamic addressing
in linux based system :

```
String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/path/to/file/QR_Code.png";
```

in windows based system :

```
String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\path\\to\\file\\QR_Code.png";
```

System.getProperty("user.dir") is your project address.

if you want to use static addressing
in linux based system :

```
String filePath = "/home/username/eclipse-workspace/test/path/to/file/QR_Code.png";
```

in windows based system :

```
String filePath = "C:\\Work\\QR_CODE\\QR_Code.png";
```